# Dynamically accessing changing variable from external .js file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to javascript (c++ normally) and I think this question should be quite basic for you all.

I have a script that gets a variable defined in an external .js file and displays it using an alert.

The code in the .html file looks like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script> 

function addScript(url){
    var extScript = document.createElement('script');
    extScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    extScript.src = url;
    extScript.id = 'extScript'

    //If there is already a script with the ID 'extScript'
    //get rid of it
    var headList = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
    var scriptList = headList[0].getElementsByTagName('script');
    for(var i = 0; i < scriptList.length; i++)
    {
        if(scriptList[i].id =='extScript')
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(scriptList[i]);
        }
    }

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(extScript);

}

function newNewChangeMode()
{
    addScript("C:/Users/Suzaku/Documents/Javascript/controller.js");
    alert("Neo controllerMode variable is reading " + controllerMode);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:newNewChangeMode()">Get externally defined mode</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And the file "controller.js" looks like this.

```
var controllerMode = 1111;
```

(that's it!)

When I click the link "get externally defined mode", my javascript runs and the alert is displayed correctly. Displaying "Neo controllerMode variable is reading 1111".

However, if I change the variable controllerMode's definition (in controller.js) to

```
 var controllerMode = 2222;
```

,hit save, and click the the button again (without refreshing), it still alerts "Neo controllerMode variable is reading 1111". Whereas it **SHOULD** say "Neo controllerMode variable is reading 2222".

It would seem that this script is not being added dynamically. I need to be able to change this variable without having to refresh the .html.

Thanks in advance,

Guy

Comment: the usual way to refresh content without reloading the html would be to use ajax, for your problem you could try adding random GET parameters to the javascript file, like "controller.js?"+new Date().getTime(); this prevents caching

Comment: This won't work because your dynamically script is loaded and executed asynchronously. You should also look into setting up a localhost server so you don't run into access restrictions to that file.

Comment: also browsers usually restrict local file access, and if they / or you allow it, you need to use the file:/// prefix. try opening C:/Users/Suzaku/Documents/Javascript/controller.js in your browser (shouldnt work), then file:///C:/Users/Suzaku/Documents/Javascript/controller.js (should create a warning)

Comment: *"Loading a new script that redefines a var"* is not the proper way to modify application state. It's more common to that the application requests an update via an HTTP request.

Comment: @x4rf41 when you say "prevent caching" do you mean that my browser is storing a local copy of the "old" .js file and reading from it rather than getting a fresh copy? What is the GET parameter of AJAX for?
And okay I'll prefix file:/// to my filepaths.

Comment: nevermind, thanks for your help. I've been pointed in the right direction with AJAX and httprequests, and research is progressing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your browser is only retrieving the cached javascript file. Make sure you go directly to your updated javascript file (controller.js) and hit F5 to ENSURE that you are loading a new version, not the cached one. Otherwise your browser will keep plugging the old, cached script (which has 1111 defined) into your script. Common problem!